ip route add with ioctl
For send broadcast UDP messages i use next:
ip route add 255.255.255.255/32 dev eth0
So, for call this one from my application i use system().
But as i kno i can use it with ioctl function.
ioctl(sockfd, SIOCADDRT, &route))

But i don't fineded any examples.... Please help.
I tryed next:
int sockfd;
struct rtentry route;
struct sockaddr_in *addr;
int err = 0;
// create the socket
if(sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)<0){
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}
memset(&route, 0, sizeof(route));
addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_gateway;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.2.15");
addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_dst;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) &route.rt_genmask;
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("255.255.255.255");
route.rt_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
route.rt_metric = 0;
if ((err = ioctl(sockfd, SIOCADDRT, &route)) != 0) {
    perror("SIOCADDRT failed");
    exit(1);
}
return 0;

But get SIOCADDRT failed: Invalid argument

Broadcast packets are not routable, so there should be no need to mess with the host's routing table. Why can't you just send the message to 255.255.255.255?

I use   bA = QHostAddress("255.255.255.255");
broadcastUdp->writeDatagram(msg.toAscii(), bA, 2857); For send datagramm. And without  ip route add 255.255.255.255/32 dev eth0  i get error and data not transmited

If your local network is 10.0.2.15 then your broadcast dest address is something like 10.0.255.255.

Do you have multiple network adapters, and want to control which one the broadcast gets sent on?

Section 5.3.5 in RFC 1812, "Requirements for IP Version 4 Routers", mentions that routers must not forward packets with a destination of 255.255.255.255 (aka "limited broadcast address").  So it's not allowed in the routing table.

Ok. I already can send 255.255.255.255 UDP packets after ip route add 255.255.255.255/32 dev eth0. And how i can do same in my C++ code?
